# AsyncTask - How to use a Handler with postDelayed(Runnable, int) inside an AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, runnable, android-handler

I'm trying to write from a BufferedInputStream, I used `while` statement before and it worked well, but now I want to delay the loop of writing each `250 millisecond`. So, I thought about using a `Handler` with `postDelayed`.

This was my code using `while`:

```
while (count = input.read(data)) > 0){
//File writing...
}
```

But when I turned it to this:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //File writing...
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }, 250);
```

I got this **RuntimeException**:

*Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare().*

I think, it says that I cant create a handler inside a thread (AsyncTask/Thread), but I hope someone has a workaround for this. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling Thread.sleep() instead of calling postDelayed on a hanler, because inside the doInBackround method you are already in backround thread and there is no issues in calling sleep for a small time interval

```
  try {
        Thread.sleep(250)   
        //File writing...
  }catch (IOException e) {

      }catch (InterruptedException e) {

      }
```

`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I did put `Thread.sleep(250)` inside `while` statement and did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, `Handler` posts messages to the `Thread` that you create it on - this means you created your handler on another thread where the looping thing isn't set up by default (whereas on main thread the looping thing is set up by default - thats why handlers work right away when created on main thread).

You can use standard Java `Timer` for scheduling actions in future, this timer uses its own thread to execute your actions, example is:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your action
            }
        }, your delay);
```

Another solution would be to use RxJava, however if you are unfamilliar with it, it takes some time to learn. Example of code that runs your action on another thread, returns result on main thread and is delayed by 250 milliseconds :

```
  (Kotlin here) Completable.fromAction(object : Action {
        override fun run() {
            // your action
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .delay(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe()
```

`AsyncTask` is generally obsolete to do any threading